# Open cmd in folder without being in that folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a shortcut,bat or exe that will open the command line in a specific folder within the current path the shortcut/bat/exe resides.

My example being the shortcut/bat/exe is located in

```
C:\Users\"user"\Desktop
```

I want to open the cmd in `Folder`

```
C:\Users\"user"\Desktop\Folder
```

But I don't want it to be dependent on the full path. I want to be able to move the exe and folder together to another location and it still work. So I want the exe to start cmd.exe in current path + \Folder

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe  +  \Folder
```

Comment: You could use `%USERPROFILE%` which expands to the current user's profile, like `C:\Users\jackjameshoward\Desktop\Folder`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just put "cd folder" in the bat file.

exe would depend on what you use to create it, and don't know about shortcuts.

Also you can use %cd% in bat files to get current path.

C:\Users\user>echo %windir%\system32\cmd.exe %cd%\Folder

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe C:\Users\user\Folder

Comment: I created the .bat with the following which seemed to do the trick `start %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k cd "Folder"`

Answer (score 0):

See `call /?` for a list of filenames/paths. This is in a batch not shortcut. `%0` is the batchfile.

```
cd "%~dp0\folder"
```

> Substitution of batch parameters (%n) has been enhanced.  You can
>      now use the following optional syntax:
>
> ```
>   %~1         - expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
>    %~f1        - expands %1 to a fully qualified path name
>    %~d1        - expands %1 to a drive letter only
>    %~p1        - expands %1 to a path only
>    %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
>    %~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
>    %~s1        - expanded path contains short names only
>    %~a1        - expands %1 to file attributes
>    %~t1        - expands %1 to date/time of file
>    %~z1        - expands %1 to size of file
>    %~$PATH:1   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                   environment variable and expands %1 to the fully
>                   qualified name of the first one found.  If the
>                   environment variable name is not defined or the
>                   file is not found by the search, then this
>                   modifier expands to the empty string
> ```
>
> The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
>
> ```
>   %~dp1       - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only
>    %~nx1       - expands %1 to a file name and extension only
>    %~dp$PATH:1 - searches the directories listed in the PATH
>                   environment variable for %1 and expands to the
>                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
>    %~ftza1     - expands %1 to a DIR like output line
> ```